# NppExec plugin ends output at first colon

Tags: notepad++, typescript, nppexec

I'm experimenting with TypeScript, and I'm using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to compose [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/), and the [NppExec](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/NppExec/) plugin to compile my scripts.  Seems like it should work, but there's one very strange problem: NppExec only shows me the output up to the `:` before the text of the first warning/error message.  For instance, let's say that the compilation output should be this:

```
C:/temp/tstest/test.ts(26,14): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
C:/temp/tstest/test.ts(33,9): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

What I will see in the NppExec Console window is:

```
node C:\temp\tstest\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js C:\temp\tstest\test.ts
Process started >>>
C:/temp/tstest/test.ts(26,14): <<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

Notice that it terminated the output after the first `):`.

Very interestingly, if I change the JavaScript engine from Node to cscript (Windows Script Host), then it works... but takes forever!  Here's what I see if I execute the same command with cscript:

```
cscript C:\temp\tstest\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc.js C:\temp\tstest\test.ts
Process started >>>
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:/temp/tstest/test.ts(26,14): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
C:/temp/tstest/test.ts(33,9): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

Any suggestions on where to go with this?  I'd much rather use Node, as it's much faster...

Here's a video demonstrating all this:
http://screencast.com/t/xxgodAU8

**Edit:** It turns out if you pass the `-w` switch (the "watch files and rebuild on change" switch) to tsc.js, it will work when executed by Node... but it doesn't build just once, it continues build and the process won't end until you kill it.

Answer (score 1):

I started a notepad ++ plugin project. 
you can find it here: 
https://github.com/hansrwindhoff/nppPluginTypescript.git

does compile on save 
and runs js in nodejs

If someone wants to put intelli-sense, that would be great!

There is a syntax coloring xml file at:
https://gist.github.com/wate/5077019
this gist is not related to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for you but I could give you some ideas on a plan of attack.

Probably the whole message is being output but some special character or sequence is making Notepad++ stop processing it.  Redirect the output to a file to see what's going on there.  The [hex editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/) plugin might help.  With that knowledge you can pipe the command output through a tool like [awk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) or [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) to rewrite the offending bits so Notepad++ likes it.

Comment: I'll give that a go, but I'm baffled as to why this all works if you pass the -w thread.  I would expect the output to be byte-for-byte identical on each compilation, with or without the -w switch.

Answer (score 0):

I started a feature request at Codeplex a time ago. Problem seems to be the way how nodejs flushes its buffer. See the discussions at github and codeplex:

http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/115

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4640#issuecomment-12542632

You may want to vote for the request so its priority goes up.